# Javascript extract response headers from loaded img

Tags: javascript, html

I have a server side app that will return an image along with some JSON data in the response header.

On the client side I have a simple html page. Imagine I load an image as follows:

`<img src="http://www.myserverapp.com/image1" />`

On the same page, is it possible to use some javascript to extract the response headers that were returned when the browser requested that image while loading the page? If so - how can this be done?

The alternative is to split up the image and JSON data into two separate resources and have the javascript send a request to the server for just the data seperately, but I was thinking if both the image and JSON data could be returned as part of the browser's image request that could be a performance improvement and make things a little more streamlined.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** I am not wanting to load the image dynamically using javascript - I know that I could do that and then extract the header information that way but I am looking for a solution where the browser loads the image normally and then some javascript code retroactively goes in and finds out the response headers for the image request the browser made.

Comment: You can use data uris to set the image source in the DOM, and the image can be serialized as base64 inside the JSON. BUT, I would rather have the image load as a normal asset and keep the json light.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the image via XHR and get any of the response headers you want, [like this](http://jsbin.com/mezuxevihe/edit?js,console).

```js
var url = 'https://placehold.it/400x400';
var proxy = 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=';
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open('GET', proxy + url, true);
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        console.log(client.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
    }
};
```

*Note I've added a proxy in this example due to CORS issues, but you can leave this out in your code*.

Comment: Thanks - I understand I could load the image dynamically using JS - but I'd rather not do that. I think my question maybe wasn't clear enough. See my edit.